# fetch the whole desktop/screen using gnome-extension?

Tags: screen, desktop, clutter, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm working on gnome-extensions (javascript) and i would like to know if it's possible to fetch/capture a desktop/screen object to apply modifications on it.

For example getting a window i use this code:

```
let app= app_system.get_running();
for(i = 0; i < app.length; i++) {
    let window = app[i].get_windows();
```

There is something similar to grab the desktop ?

Such as `system.get_desktop()`.

Comment: Check this one: http://www.roojs.org/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/seed/Gdk.Screen.html#expand
Looks hardware related !? I will have a look on it

Comment: Don't use that website: it's completely out of date. It also refers to Seed, the JavaScriptCore-based introspection binding for JS. The GNOME Shell is written using GJS, the MozJs-based binding instead, which means that there are some differences. Plus, as I said, bot Seed and that website are not maintained any more, and woefully out of date.

Comment: This is out of date. But some options are still usefull. Anyway, does Gdk.Screen is still in stable release ? And does it correspond to what i need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really use the Clutter API for this; the screenshot needs to be taken with the help of the compositor at the right time, and saving the data to a file has to be done complete asynchronously, to avoid blocking the compositor loop.

GNOME Shell exposes a DBus API for taking screenshot and screencasts, which is useful for external services (for instance, `gnome-screenshot` uses that API, if present, instead of using X11 API). Since you're writing an extension, you can use the same internal API to take a screenshot by importing the `Shell` module and using its `Shell.Screenshot` class:

```
const Shell = imports.gi.Shell;
const Lang = imports.lang;

let shooter = new Shell.Screenshot();
shooter.screenshot (filename, includePointer, onScreenshotComplete);
```

Where `filename` is the path to the file you wish to save; `includePointer` is a boolean that controls whether the pointer should be taken into the screenshot; and `onScreenshotComplete` is a function called when the screenshot has been saved.

Comment: Ok, so no way to make it live ? I mean,i cant use screenshot for apply shader on my desktop.

Comment: You're literally asking a different thing, now; you should be more explicit in what you want to achieve when you ask a question. If you want to apply a shader to a window then you need to walk the scene graph and find the window actor you want, and use a ShaderEffect. If you want to apply a ShaderEffect to a region on the screen you'll need to apply the shader to the stage, and upload the region coordinates to the shader as a uniform.

Comment: Thanks you answered to the post question plus my question in the comment above.